# Anotação de tipos em funções assíncronas no TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, tipagem, promises

Sou novo no TypeScript e tenho a seguinte dúvida. É preciso estar explicito o tipo do retorno de uma requisição `fetch`?

```js
const getPeoples: () => {
  userId: number,
  id: number,
  title: string,
  body: string,
}[] = async() => {
  const url =  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=2"
  const response: Response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json()

  return data;
}
```

O editor está acusando um erro falando que a variável `data` é um tipo `Promise<any>` (o que é claro) e que não está retornando o tipo que explicitei. Então, é um má prática deixar o código da seguinte forma?

```js
const getPeoples: () => Promise<any> = async() => {
  const url =  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=2"
  const response: Response = await fetch(url);
  const data: Promise<any> = await response.json();

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é uma má prática anotar o tipo explicitamente quando o tipo for `any`. Muito pelo contrário, é uma ótima prática definir tipos explícitos quando a não é possível inferir o tipo – como nesse caso.

Você não estará livre de erros, já que eventualmente você pode atribuir um tipo "errado", mas esse nem sempre é o caso.

Nesse tipo de caso – uma requisição HTTP –, a não ser que você estiver usando um [*type guard*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) (que traria o máximo de segurança de tipos possível), anotar um tipo à `any` é uma opção válida também.

O problema é que o tipo que você está anotando como retorno da função é:

```
{
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}[];
```

E esse tipo é diferente (e não atribuível) ao tipo `Promise<any>`, porque aquele tipo não é uma `Promise`.

Também vale mencionar que **toda** [função assíncrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas) (anotada com `async`) retornará uma promessa, o que também invalida a anotação explícita.

Para corrigir, mantendo ainda o retorno explícito, você deve explicitar que a função está retornando uma `Promise` de algo. Logo, a anotação de retorno deverá ser algo como:

```
Promise<{
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}[]>;
```

`Promise<T>` é um tipo genérico embutido na biblioteca do TypeScript. Você pode consultar [aqui](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/a60feb2d3983e4b57a257acfefcc8477e66b9425/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1414).

Isso significa uma promessa que se resolverá em um array de objetos (com a assinatura especificada).

Então, a sua função ficará algo como:

```js
const getPeople: () => Promise<{
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}[]> = async () => {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=2';
  const response: Response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
};
```

No entanto, eu não recomendo utilizar a anotação desse jeito, já que você está dando um tipo à uma *arrow function*, e não necessariamente ao seu retorno. Pessoalmente, eu faria assim:

```
interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

// Estamos anotando o tipo explicitamente no retorno da função:
//                          ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
async function getPeople(): Promise<Post[]> {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=2';
  const response: Response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
}
```

<sup>[Veja no TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOZkG8BQyyArptAJIAmAXMiMQLYBG0A3IcsDXYy1O0TDAwAGwi1sUUAHMByJukoBPCWCkhZ%20AL758Aej3IAotjgMsyOCHRgrldMgdCADg4gAPZyOAJhZiOAo1shQEGDoUMGUcMgwxCAA5wDH6NT6hkSZWdk52YDJhAWFRcX4cJhKIAix8QhC6CDI0mGoEOheEAAUAJS0qFDoDMBkADwY2ADaALoAfHgcCPXYJFAiyAC8yADkABZgYM6Y1AYAVpj1XogQ2%20gilNAAdGBKzj6KEPcLDHqu2JgA-AB9byDMBrABMmzkCxAS1CmFcMPEyAAShB4YsUBs4AB3ODCWJhBDbDrEFZdKGLHDRWzrSy4-FwhFke6nerddgcUJgUkNalwdhaIA)</sup>

Uma outra opção é anotar o tipo diretamente na variável e deixar o TypeScript inferir o retorno da função:

```
interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

async function getPeople() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=2';
  const response: Response = await fetch(url);

  // Estamos anotando o tipo explicitamente na variável:
  //          ↓↓↓↓↓↓
  const data: Post[] = await response.json();

  return data;
}
```

<sup>[Veja no TypeScript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHsDOZkG8BQyyArptAJIAmAXMiMQLYBG0A3IcsDXYy1O0TDAwAGwi1sUUAHMByJukoBPCWCkhZ%20AL758cTEpAJkMYkaHoQyaRDCoI6AA5iAFAEo8HBJewkoI5ABeZAByAAswMEdMagB6WIArTEtnRAgw9BFKaAA6MCVHYG9snO8GWMcsMEwAfgB9EWAGYUCAJhC5bxBfKAhMSu7xZAAlPoGyIOQ4AHc4YRNbBDCXYn83dg545ABRbDgGLCmQdDA4EEp0ZEuhSuQIAA9nIuF9iHAUEDhkADc4KQBD74QETUTaxIgQyHIQDJhLC4V4fDhKHBTrQMNgANoAXUmMzmOF6-R8EBySUs7g2RF6YFWVmRp3YWiAA)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!